# ASP registration using sql table complains that ID cannot be null

Tags: sql, asp-classic, registration

i have created a registration page in asp.net and a registration table on sql server. the table requires an ID, Name, user, pass, etc. my registration page sends all that information with the exception of an ID, i want the table to add the ID automatically. so when i try to use the registration, it complains that ID cannot be null. as it is now in the table, ID cannot be null and i forgot to make it auto increment.
if i make the ID auto increment, will that work, or will it still ask me for an ID when i send the information via asp?
or do i still have to send the parameter for ID from the asp page and make it null. allow null for the ID and make it auto increment?

whats the correct way of doing it?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Change your table's `id` to auto increment and it will work and after that you will not needed  to pass the `id` for creating new registration.But if you edit your data then you must supply the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server (which I am assuming because of the statement "on sql server"), then the appropriate syntax in the `create table` statement for such an "auto incremented" id is:

```
 id int not null identity(1, 1)
```

If the table is empty, you can alter the table by doing:

```
 alter table t alter column id int identity(1, 1);
```

Typically, this would also be a primary key on the table.  If you are not using SQL Server, there is similar syntax in other databases.